# Python/JSON: Errors one after another

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am following an online tutorial for making a chatbot...here is the code for the beginning portion

```
import sqlite3
import json
from datetime import datetime

timeframe = '2015-01'
sql_transaction = []

connection = sqlite3.connect('{}.db'.format(timeframe))
c = connection.cursor()

def create_table():
    c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS parent_reply(parent_id TEXT PRIMARY KEY, comment_id TEXT UNIQUE, parent TEXT, comment TEXT, subreddit TEXT, unix INT, score INT)")

def format_data(data):
    data = data.replace('\n', ' newlinechar ').replace('\r', ' newlinechar ').replace('"', "'")
    return data

def find_parent(pid):
    try:
        sql = "SELECT comment FROM parent_reply WHERE comment_id = '{}' LIMIT 1".format(pid)
        c.execute(sql)
        result = c.fetchone()
        if result != None:
            return result[0]
        else: return False
    except Exception as e:
        #print(str(e))
        return False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_table()
    row_counter = 0
    paired_rows = 0

    with open('C:/Users/oriba/Desktop/Month of Reddit/RC_2015-01'.format(timeframe.split('-')[0], timeframe), encoding='ISO-8859-1', buffering=1000) as f:
        for row in f:
            print(row)
            row_counter += 1
            row = json.load(row)
            parent_id = row['parent_id']
            body = format_data(row['body'])
            created_utc = row['created_utc']
            score = row['score']
            comment_id = row['name']
            subreddit = row['subreddit']
            parent_data = find_parent(parent_id)
```

When that runs, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/oriba/Desktop/Month of Reddit/chatbot.py", line 37, in <module>
    for row in f:
  File "C:\Users\oriba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 97: character maps to <undefined>
```

After searching online, I found that adding "encoding='ISO-8859-1'" to 'with open()' should fix it...then I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/oriba/Desktop/Month of Reddit/chatbot.py", line 40, in <module>
    row = json.load(row)
  File "C:\Users\oriba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\json\__init__.py", line 296, in load
BZh91AY&SYÔAÙÕÿî»ÿÿÿúÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿc*è`  1Ï. ñÕ ¢U±Ã$'¤;\=@  ÝX9kl´ÜÎ¹KW; É@ Ò PQáGF  PÝ  Û   P      :è  
    return loads(fp.read(),
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

And now I'm at a loss. I know this is a lot, this is complex for me. I appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 0):

`json.loads()` does the job.

`loads()` read from a str object while `load()` read from a File object

You code is

```
for row in f:
    ...
```

`row` here is a str